# magento 2 admin base urls

Tags: magento2

There seems to be an issue with google not showing my catalog and product images in google search results, just wondering if my magento admin base (secure/unsecure) urls are set correctly? i have seen many variations on the web for this so not too sure and i am non-technical so i don't want to break the site or admin panel access if i make any changes. when a sitemap is generated it generates /pub/sitemap.xml and my secure urls point to /pub/static/.....pub/media/

Can anyone advise the correct settings? and if changes are made in admin panel is there more actions to take with server?
Thanks in advance[image]

Answer (score 0):

With Magento, it is always the easy path to work with it rather than against.. this is my rule of thumb..

Now, in your context, your screenshot shows you have modified some entries in the system when in fact looking at the values you have entered, it seems you would want your system to work as it does by default:

- for instance, your media files do not use any CDN and instead your media files do live in the `pub/media` folder like Magento does by default

Below, I add a screenshot of a default Magento install I have locally. You will see the values are less customised.

[image]

I suggest as a way forward to do the following steps:

- particularly because you are not a technical resource, do ensure you have backup of your system so that you can go back to something you know how it works and what is wrong (if you can't do this because you are working on production, then it may be advisable to seek help)
- empty the fields that are not empty from your config and are empty on my config: this should be safe to do as as I say these values are the default values than Magento gets shipped with
- the Base link can be changed as well although it is not as important I think. I will not provide details on this point just so that we remain simple for you to find a solution to your problem

good luck

Comment: Thank you Herve, very much appreciated.

Comment: good to have you you onboard at Magento Stack Exchange, fire away if you have more concerns, thanks for your update